# How to achieve the asynchronous in vertx

Tags: vert.x

I have making a call to mongoclient in vertx and getting the response through handler. How can I use the `subscrbeOn` for make sure crating the thread from threadpool. Could you please help me.

I want use the below code in same way as above:

```
ObservableHandler<AsyncResult<UserDetail>> observable = RxHelper.observableHandler();
```

is there any other options to achieve asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Vert.x is asynchronous, if you have achieved getting response through handler which means it is asynchronous. I guess you are looking for reactive(rx) mongoclient.

Check this: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/rx-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/rxjava/database/mongo/Client.java

Comment: io.vertx.rxjava.ext.mongo.MongoClient; is this asynchronus client?

Comment: Yes, it is asynchronous.

Comment: when making a call to mango db ideally it should use worker thread but in my case its taking event loop thread. How can we achieve this